# CSS to set color of the active tab

Tags: asp.net

I am having tabs in my webform.I have taken list of menus.

I have set hover effect.I have to set color of the active tab.And color should be there      till I select another tab.But the color get only when I clicked one of the tab and disappears before selecting another tab.I have tried it many times but I am not getting proper output.Please give me some solution for this.Thnks in advance.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Poll</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
<ul>
.tabs
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden; /* background: #F9F9F9;*/
    float: right; /*border-bottom:1px solid #000000;*/
    /*background-color: #FF7800;*/
    padding-top:14px;}
.tabs ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;      
}
.tabs li
{
    float:left;
    /*width:50px;*/
   /*background-color:#6600FF;*/
    }
.tabs li a {

    color:#FF6700;
    /*background-color:#FFC480;*/
    display:block;
    float:left;

    height:25px;
    width:120px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:none;
   /* border-left:1px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;   */ 
}
.tabs li a:hover {

    text-decoration:underline;
    /*background-color:#FFBA00;*/
    /*background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;*/

}

.tabs ul li a:active
{
    color:#FF9000;
    background-color:#FFB140;

}
```

I have given the my code.So please suggest me some solution for this.I required this for my two projects.
For tabs,I have set color for text of tabs only,and on mouse hover effect I have set text-decoration property.I have to set background color for the tabs when I select/clicked on one of the tab and the effect should be there till another tab get selected.

Comment: `I have given the my code` the code is not relevant, simply take the base file name, and use an if condition, match the values, if returns true, print out the active css class, else leave it blank

Comment: :active will change the color when you click the link (only while you hold mouse click).

Comment: Check this http://forums.aspfree.com/html-javascript-css-help-7/active-tab-color-change-383022.html you can do this jQuery or other javascript also.

Comment: try with javascript or jquery